# Which one is correct: "decide the amount" or "decide on the amount"?

Tags: prepositions

Can you please tell me which one is correct: *decide the amount* or *decide on the amount*? For example:

> I think we need to pay Mike more for the job and I suggest we **decide the amount** when it's completed.
>
> I think we need to pay Mike more for the job and I suggest we **decide on the amount** when it's completed.

Are both correct? if so, is there a nuance of difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that the two phrases are used in pretty much equal measure, but not in all contexts.

Merriam Webster defines the phrasal verb **decide on** to mean: **to choose, typically after giving thought to something.** It gives the following examples where the verb **decide** alone doesn't fit:

**He decided on blue rather than green.**
**I am having trouble deciding on a gift for them.**

When it comes to amounts, the preposition/s **on/upon** are not required but are optional. So you can decide an amount or decide on/upon it.

I cannot think of any distinction or nuances between the two in this context.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decide%20on%2Fupon

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decide+the+amount%2Cdecide+on+the+amount&year

Answer (score 2):

When you determine how much you will charge for your service, you have *decided the amount [you will charge your customer].*  No one else is needed for you to *decide the amount [you will charge].*

When you are **negotiating** a cash exchange with a customer, friend, colleague, you and the other individual are *deciding **on** the amount [that will be paid].*  *Deciding on the amount,* means you and someone else are coming to an agreement.